# Display Parameter(Multi-value) in Report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Can anyone tell me how to display all the selected value of my multi value parameter in SSRS report. When giving `parameter.value` option it gives error.

Comment: Here's the way to do it using the JOIN function, as part of a larger blog on multivalue parameters: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s187/multivalue-report-builder.htm.

Answer (score 158):

You can use the "Join" function to create a single string out of the array of labels, like this:

```
=Join(Parameters!Product.Label, ",")
```

Comment: If he is adding the join expr to the header, it would cause the results to grow over the body of the report no?

Comment: Thanks for giving a great answer before I had to tear my hair out while googling!

Comment: or `=Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ",")`

Comment: What if you have page breaks on each product? Is it possible to display one product per page?

Answer (score 12):

=Join(Parameters!Product.Label, vbcrfl) for new line

Comment: @nadiObi : It should be [vbCrLf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223391/7794769) instead.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't know about the join function - Nice! I had written a function that I placed in the code section (report properties->code tab:

```
Public Function ShowParmValues(ByVal parm as Parameter) as string
   Dim s as String 

      For i as integer = 0 to parm.Count-1
         s &= CStr(parm.value(i)) & IIF( i < parm.Count-1, ", ","")
      Next
  Return s
End Function
```

Comment: +1  This works in a report header where the "Join" solution requires a table (which can't go into a report header).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone else finds this useful:

Using the Join is the best way to use a multi-value parameter. But what if you want to have an efficient 'Select All'? If there are 100s+ then the query will be very inefficient.

To solve this instead of using a SQL Query as is, change it to using an expression (click the Fx button top right) then build your query something like this (speech marks are necessary):

```
= "Select * from tProducts Where 1 = 1 " 
IIF(Parameters!ProductID.Value(0)=-1,Nothing," And ProductID In (" & Join(Parameters!ProductID.Value,"','") & ")")
```

In your Parameter do the following:

```
    SELECT -1 As ProductID, 'All' as ProductName Union All
    Select  
    tProducts.ProductID,tProducts.ProductName
    FROM
    tProducts
```

By building the query as an expression means you can make the SQL Statement more efficient but also handle the difficulty SQL Server has with handling values in an 'In' statement.