# Displaying placeholder for multiple value parameter in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Good Afternoon All

I use SSRS all the time and when making reports i normally insert a placeholder at the title, so whenever i write anything in a specific parameter, it will show on the placeholder using the tool tip.

I have now gone onto selecting multiple items on my parameter and the problem that i am getting is that the placeholder can only show one of many i selected, i have been trying to find out how i can use the placeholder to show all items i select, but had no luck at all.

Could you help me in the situation that i am in...

Comment: Do you mean an expression like `=Join(Parameters!MyParameter.Label, ",")`, which displays all selected values from a multi-value parameter as a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Parameter(Multi-value) in Report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300339/display-parametermulti-value-in-report)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look [here](https://popbi.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/displaying-the-selections-for-ssrs-multi-select-parameters-in-a-report/)

```
=Join(Parameters!ParameterName.Label, ",")
```