# Differences Between vbLf, vbCrLf & vbCr Constants

Tags: vb.net, printing, constants, msgbox

I used constants like `vbLf` , `vbCrLf` & `vbCr` in a *MsgBox*; it produces same output in a MsgBox (Text "Hai" appears in a first paragraph and a word "Welcome" appears in a next Paragraph )

```
MsgBox("Hai" & vbLf & "Welcome")
MsgBox ("Hai" & vbCrLf & "Welcome")
MsgBox("Hai" & vbCr & "Welcome")
```

I know `vbLf` , `vbCrLf` & `vbCr` are used for print and display functions.

I want to know the Difference between the `vbLf` , `vbCrLf` & `vbCr` constants.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
 Constant   Value               Description
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 vbCr       Chr(13)             Carriage return
 vbCrLf     Chr(13) & Chr(10)   Carriage return–linefeed combination
 vbLf       Chr(10)             Line feed
```

- **vbCr** : - ***return to line beginning***
  Represents a *carriage-return* character for print and display functions.
- **vbCrLf** : - ***similar to pressing Enter***
  Represents a *carriage-return* character combined with a *linefeed character* for print and display 
  functions.
- **vbLf** : - ***go to next line***
  Represents a *linefeed character* for print and display functions.

---

Read More from [Constants Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is `vbNewLine` a mere alias for CRLF, or a fuzzy, obsolete _platform-dependant newline_?

Comment: ＋１for the simplest expalantion of the CRLF concept: similar to pressing Enter.

Answer (score 46):

The three constants have similar functions nowadays, but different historical origins, and very occasionally you may be required to use one or the other.

You need to think back to the days of old manual typewriters to get the origins of this. There are two distinct actions needed to start a new line of text:

1. move the typing head back to the left. In practice in a typewriter this is done by moving the roll which carries the paper (the "carriage") all the way back to the right -- the typing head is fixed. This is a **carriage return**.
2. move the paper up by the width of one line. This is a **line feed**.

In computers, these two actions are represented by two different characters - carriage return is `CR`, ASCII character 13, `vbCr`; line feed is `LF`, ASCII character 10, `vbLf`. In the old days of teletypes and line printers, the printer needed to be sent these two characters -- traditionally in the sequence `CRLF` -- to start a new line, and so the `CRLF` combination -- `vbCrLf` -- became a traditional line ending sequence, in **some** computing environments.

The problem was, of course, that it made just as much sense to only use one character to mark the line ending, and have the terminal or printer perform both the carriage return and line feed actions automatically. And so before you knew it, we had 3 different valid line endings: `LF` alone (used in Unix and Macintoshes), `CR` alone (apparently used in older Mac OSes) and the `CRLF` combination (used in DOS, and hence in Windows). This in turn led to the complications of DOS / Windows programs having the option of opening files in `text mode`, where any `CRLF` pair read from the file was converted to a single `CR` (and vice versa when writing).

So - to cut a (much too) long story short - there are historical reasons for the existence of the three separate line separators, which are now often irrelevant: and perhaps the best course of action in .NET is to use `Environment.NewLine` which means someone else has decided for you which to use, and future portability issues should be reduced.

Comment: One addition to that... from the old days... it was common to use the carriage return on it's own so you could OVER-TYPE the text you had already printed. This was often used to add highlighting or other markings, for example ---- characters were overtyped to indicate a crossed out word. When the changeable font "Ball" typewriter came out you could even change the font of specific words in a sentence that way.

Comment: That also brings up another historical difference. Backspace VS Delete. On computers. Backspace on a computer moves the cursor back one position and deletes the previous character. This is different from the tradition role which was to move back one space and NOT delete, but over-type.