# Replace only vbLf (not vbCrLf)

Tags: vb.net

I am importing CSV file with multiple lines where the end of the line is a `vbCrLf`.

The problem is that sometimes I am getting into the fields with the value `vbLf`.

I would just like to replace the `vbLf`.

When i use the code below replaces the `vbLf` and `vbCrLf` as indicating the end of the line:

```
txt = txt.Replace ( vbLf , "")
```

How do I replace only the `vbLf`?

Comment: Use a regular expression with a [negative lookbehind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to assert there is no `vbCr` before the `vbLf`.

Comment: @GSerg, how i create the negative in this case? Thanks

Comment: Click the link, scroll down to "negative lookbehind", copy the construct to your regular expression and note that `vbCr` is `\r` and `vbLf` is `\n`.

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem, you cannot use StreamReader to read such a file.  It will detect the line feed character as a line ending.  Writing your own custom StreamReader class, well, have fun.

Comment: `txt = txt.Replace(vbLf, "")` should replace only `vbLf` - I don't see how it would replaace `vbCrLf`.....

Comment: @Tim, vbLf = \n, vbCr = \r, vbCrLf = \r\n, the replace remove "half" vbCrLf and modify it in vbCr

Comment: @HansPassant is right...OP check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223228/differences-between-vblf-vbcrlf-vbcr-constants

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future:
If the line ends or starts with vbLf(Chr(10)) you can just TRIM each line, like so:

```
str = str.TrimStart(Chr(10))
str = str.Trim(Chr(10))
str = str.TrimEnd(Chr(10))
```