# Find newline in Excel with VBA Using Range.Find()

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find a word with new line in the excel sheet using VBA. To do that I have written the VBA macro as follow:

```
Set columnIndex1 = headerRow.Find("AAA " & vbCrLf & "BBB", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

where the text I have to search is:
*AAA *newline*
BBB*
VBA not detecting new line. What could be the solution?

Comment: You search for this `"AAA " & vbCrLf & "BBB"` are you sure your first line `AAA` ends with a space before the line break comes? Shouldn't it be ``"AAA" & vbCrLf & "BBB"``?

Comment: As @Pᴇʜ mentioned. Ideally use the `TRIM()` function to get rid of any extra whitespaces and ensure the data you are comparing is correct.

Comment: how do you realize the "newline" in the cell? By alt+enter? this results in "AAA" & Chr(10) & "BBB" and not "AAA" & vbCrLf & "BBB" - Excel 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record a macro, writing the value. Then see how excel interprets it and search for it. This is how it takes it, when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "23AAA" & Chr(10) & "BBBSD"
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Then something like this works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim colIndex As Range
    Set colIndex = Range("A1:Z100").Find("AAA" & Chr(10) & "BBB", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Debug.Print colIndex.Address

End Sub
```

Or use `VbLf`, which is the same as `Chr(10)`. [Differences Between vbLf, vbCrLf & vbCr Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223228/differences-between-vblf-vbcrlf-vbcr-constants).