# SSRS Export to PDF character spacing issues on Windows 2016 server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

```
Using: SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services,
Product Version: 11.0.7462.6
Report Server Mode: Native
```

A server side rdl report is generated as PDF.

[Sample rdl file contents here](https://pastebin.com/xmf8t4hx)

On a Windows 2008 R2 Server, the generated PDF looks ok:

[image]

On a Windows 2016 Server, there are minor spacing issues with the PDF (see bits underlined in red):

[image]

i.e. for line "1", the spacing between the lower case "l" and number "2" is non-existent. The text value for line "1" looks like this:

```
="Chos achrPapis Frhmistisya Sdt AFT hTe apetociaschmrdtP rilyus TtFam l25044025 - stuTr" & vbcrlf & "a"
```

Note that line "2" displays ok. Line 2's text value is the same as that for Line 1, but only has 1 line:

```
="Chos achrPapis Frhmistisya Sdt AFT hTe apetociaschmrdtP rilyus TtFam l25044025 - stuTr"
```

So it seems having a carriage return is a factor in this problem.

Also, in line 3, there should be a space between "world" and "Support", but there isn't.

The problem only seems to be on export to PDF. The report looks fine when generated in Html, Word etc.

Can anyone shed any light?

EDIT: I should add that there are no special characters or anything like that being used in the report.

Comment: Maybe something to do with encoding?? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c25ea5d1-baad-492c-88e3-57b7551eac16/ssrs-2012-export-to-pdf-encoding-fonts?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @JeremyThompson -  I wouldn't have thought so. The problem can be reproduced with not just Calibri, but also other common fonts I have tried, like Arial. The problem can be seen, even when the generated pdf is displayed on the same server that generated the report. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Does changing `vbClrf` to the others give any clue to the line feed error, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223391/495455. Also can you confirm there is no other PDF library and the PDF DLLs are the same version, just to narrow down the differences - I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - I tried vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf before - it did not make any difference to the result. How do you check the PDF DLLs? Do you mean the reporting services rendering dlls? If so, I can confirm that the Windows 2008 and Windows 2016 servers both had the same versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moe,

I can't confirm your issue. I deployed the report on SSRS 2016, and it looks fine to me. 
I'm using:

**SSRS:** 
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 13.0.4446.0

**SQL Server:**
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) - 13.0.4446.0 (X64)   Jul 16 2017 18:08:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Maybe your CU is not the same as the one I'm using here, so I suggest updating SQL to the latest update.

See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This is actually better business practice these days. We don't wait for SQL 2000 SP4 to be released before we upgrade from SQL7. We are always on latest. Go the SSRS 2016 pathway...

Comment: @Nikola - thanks for trying it!. It's good to know that it can work on SQL Server 2016. So upgrading may be one answer.