# How to send "enter" character without giving an enter in EXCEL VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro to write a .txt file and send it to our server, but our server only recognizes a new line, if there is an "enter" (chr 10) character at the end of the line. But everytime i write chr(10) at the end of the line, it creates a new line and macro writes at the next line of it like

Example               (enter character sent here)
 <---- new line 
Next content

But server wont recognize the next content if the line before it is empty
it must be like

Example               (enter character sent here)
Next content

So far i have this to write the .txt file

```
Private Sub E16_Click()
Dim fs As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim f As Object
Dim order
pedido = Sheets("EDI").Range("I2")
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("c:\" & IIf(Range("AA24") = 2, "temp\", "") & "pc" & order & ".txt", 2, True)

f.writeline "ITP" & Sheets("EDI").Range("C2") & Sheets("EDI").Range("J2") & Sheets("EDI").Range("L2") & WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", 75) ' **Enter character must be sent here**
f.writeline Sheets("EDI").Range("M2") ' **Enter character must be sent here**
f.writeline "AE3" & Sheets("EDI").Range("J2") & "04771370000183" & Sheets("EDI").Range("J2") & WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", 83) ' **Enter character must be sent here**
```

Is there anyway to send an enter character without creating a new line? I tried to format the Enter character as a text and didnt work

Comment: [This what you're looking for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223228/differences-between-vblf-vbcrlf-vbcr-constants)

Comment: No, that will do the same as chr(10) or chr(13) or chr(10)+chr(13) i need to send Enter character as a text and do not create a new line, i tried to use that and didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are using `f.writeline` instead of `f.write`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/write-method

Comment: I didnt think about using f.write instead and send enter... that worked Thanks