# Replace LineFeed Character with Paragraph Mark that comes after a certain text

Tags: vba, loops, replace, ms-word, word-2007

[This is the Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfXDm.png)    Following is the text with Syntax: "Question[space][1-30][colon][LineFeed]"
Looks Like≔" Question 1:

### The Word 2007 File is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6jrbt4woc74nedafoe1r5/Sample-Document.docx?dl=0&rlkey=jo1yx3x1vvo6abr8uk833j8o6

### These are the Paragraphs:

**All of the Following lines are ended with Line Feed (Shift Control) Character**

*But The List is not bulleted*

- Discuss with your partner.
- Question 1:
- What ence...?
- Answer:
- There... together.
- Question 2:
- How d  suggest ...”?
- Answer:
- The sto..either.
- Question 3:
- What lessons ...?
- Answer:
- ... them.
- Question 4:
- Why do you ...?
- Answer:
- Man is  ...Scott.

### About Code

- Code will apply to document not a part
- How to replace the last "Line Feed Character" with a Paragraph Mark.
- Paragraph style of this be "myHead4"
- Before Paragraph mark I want to write: (VImp) replaced by m1, (Imp2)replaced by m2, (Imp3) replaced by m4
- Any site about Wild Card Characters
- I am using the following code, But I failed how to use do..Loop.
- I am using two seperate codes for this purpose
- All this I want because I want to include Questions in my TOC.

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDlwq.png)

```
Sub DeleteLineFeedAndTypeParagraph()

x = Asc(Selection.text)
y = Selection.Font.Color
Selection.Words(1).Select
Selection.HomeKey
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .text = "Question [0-9]{1,2}:^l"
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    x = Selection.Characters.last
    If Selection.Characters.last = chr(11) Then 'vbLf Line Break
        Selection.Characters.last = vbCr
        Selection.MoveEnd unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("myHead4")
        'x = Right(Selection, 1)
    End If
End Sub
'The Second Procedure is
Sub SelectWordAndChangeText()
Selection.Words(1).Select
Select Case Selection.text
Case "m1"
Selection.text = "VImp"
Selection.Words(1).Italic = True
Case "m2"
Selection.text = "Imp"
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you check the last character of these para with `Debug.Print Asc(para.Range.Characters.Last)` , it is 13 and with `If Selection.Characters.last = chr(11)` , you trying to replace 11. .. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223228/differences-between-vblf-vbcrlf-vbcr-constants)

Comment: para.Range ... is returning Paragraph character that is at the end of sixth line. Please see the image. @Naresh