# Need input from text boxes and create a custom statement based on inputs from text box. I need it in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need complete solution to create a template for multiple inputs through textboxes and link those with custom text in the back end. Once all the fields are entered i need the complete message to be displayed and to copy that.

for example
Text box 1: Insurance, Text box 2: PHone number and text box 3: Agent name

Output should be

Called "input from textbox 1" with phone number "input from textbox2" and spoke to "input from text box 3"

Need solution if i cannot copy message from msg box option. I am very new to VBA and just saw a simple video to create below solution

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Insurance As String

'get the data from the textbox
 Insurance = TextBox1.Text
 
Dim Phone As String
Phone = TextBox2.Text

Dim agent As String
agent = TextBox3.Text

'create the writeup
'add your code here to manipulate the data

'display the writeup in a message box
MsgBox "Notes: Called" & Insurance, "with phone number" & Phone, "and spoke to" & agent
End Sub
```

error is received in MSGBOX line.

Answer (score 0):

`MsgBox` expects the complete message text as first parameter. The (optional) second parameter defines what kind of message box you want to display (Icon, Button) and is a numeric value. For details, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)

However, you wrote

```
MsgBox "Notes: Called" & Insurance, "with phone number" & Phone, "and spoke to" & agent
```

When you have a closer look to that command, you can see that you are passing 3 strings as parameter, separated by a comma:

```
"Notes: Called" & Insurance  
"with phone number" & Phone
"and spoke to" & agent
```

So the second parameter you are passing to `MsgBox` is a String, while the function expects a number and therefore you get a type mismatch error.

Simply change the command to

```
MsgBox "Notes: Called " & Insurance & " with phone number " & Phone & " and spoke to " & agent
```

Now the pieces of the message are all concatenated and result in a single String.

Comment: Know that you can "divide" the string in multiple lines using [vbLf, vbCrLf, vbCr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223228/differences-between-vblf-vbcrlf-vbcr-constants). This way the message will looks better.

Comment: Sure. You can do a lot. But that was not the question.

Comment: Indeed. I just thought it could have been useful to add an extra tip for Kireeti Srestaluri. Of course it wasn't the point of the question. ;) Should have probably added a reference to him in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you that solution worked. Now I could see the desired result but cannot copy it. Can I get that in a text box rather than a message box where I can copy the final statement